# getting an error while running .build.sh file in cross compiler dir

Tags: c++, c, gcc, g++

Here is my console log while running .build.sh command in crosscompiler dir.

version of gcc, g++ and clang is here.

bnr@AM-PC-07:~/osxcross$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 8.3.0-6ubuntu1~18.04.1) 8.3.0
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

bnr@AM-PC-07:~/osxcross$ clang --version
clang version 6.0.0-1ubuntu2 (tags/RELEASE_600/final)
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
bnr@AM-PC-07:~/osxcross$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Here is my error log

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/CMakeTestCXXCompiler.cmake:45 (message):
The C++ compiler

"/usr/bin/clang++"

is not able to compile a simple test program.

It fails with the following output:

Change Dir: /home/bnr/osxcross/build/apple-libtapi/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/make" "cmTC_5f536/fast"
/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_5f536.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_5f536.dir/build
```

Comment: The contents of your `.build.sh` would be instrumental in forming an answer.

Comment: What you have posted is/are not error messages.  rather they are bits and pieces of what would be output.  Please copy/paste the actual output into your question